# What is the best way to determine the number of subtrees having exactly 4 nodes?

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-tree, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

Consider a rooted n node binary tree represented using pointers. The best upper bound on the time required to determine the number of subtrees having exactly 4 nodes is O(n^a Log^b(n)). Then the value of **a+10b** is __________.

---

My attempt:

Somewhere algorithm is given as following:

```
int print4Subtree(struct Node *root) {
    if (root == NULL)
      return 0;
    int l =  print4Subtree(root->left);
    int r =   print4Subtree(root->right);
    if ((l + r + 1) == 4)
       printf("%d ", root->data);
    return (l + r + 1); }
```

---

This algorithm runs O(n) time , so answer will be 1 .

Is it correct or any other better algorithm exist?

Can you explain in formal/alternative way, please.

Comment: I don't see any log factor coming into picture. Also, you *need to* visit all nodes at least once, so complexity is minimum O(n) and this algo is. So, I guess you are right.

Comment: @vish4071  Theorethically, you do not. You don't have to look for the nodes after the fifth for each subtree.

Comment: @Magisch, why not? The 5th node for some node is 4th for other.

Comment: @vish4071 But you could stop looking for that subtree then. If a node happens to be more then the fifth for one tree and linked to no other, it would not be visited.

Comment: @Magisch, No. We will have to visit that node in any case (to see if that is the one with subtree of size 4).

Comment: @Magisch: It might be that it would be possible to avoid visiting all or even O(n) nodes if the tree was represented using an array of pointers to leaves, with each node having a pointer to its parent -- since then, you could stay "low down" in the tree and stop climbing up as soon as you reach a path of length 4.  But with only down-pointers, every node needs to be visited.

Comment: @Silence: In CS, a *subtree* usually means that there are no further nodes connected below it, but in graph theory, a *subtree* does not imply this -- it just means a subgraph (subset of nodes and edges) that is also a tree.  So e.g. if you have e.g. a 10-node path with the root at one end, there are 7 subtrees according to the graph theory definition, instead of 1.  There are usually (many) more subtrees according to the graph theory definition....  This could be where the log factor comes from.

Comment: @j_random_hacker , Can you convert your comment into answer please, if you think , it's correct .

Comment: Well, it's just a guess about the intentions of the question asker...  I can make it an answer if you want, though.

Comment: @j_random_hacker in a reasonably balanced binary tree about half of the nodes are leaves (so still O(n) on average) even if we just visit the lower nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In computer science, a *subtree* usually means that there are no further nodes connected below it, but in graph theory, the term *subtree* does not imply this -- it just means a subgraph (subset of nodes and edges) that is also a tree.  So e.g. if you have a 10-node path with the root at one end, there are 7 subtrees according to the graph theory definition, instead of 1.  There are usually (many) more subtrees according to the graph theory definition...  This could be where the log factor comes from in the question.

On the other hand, there are just a **constant number** of 4-node rooted binary trees -- I count 14 in total (8 height-3 trees, 4 height-2 trees in which the root has 2 children, and 2 height-2 trees in which the root has 1 child).  So even with the new, broader definition, it would be possible to check each node in the tree to see which of the 14 possible 4-node rooted binary trees are rooted at this node, and add this count to a grand total, all in O(n) time.